# Display name along with the count in descending order in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two models within my models.py file as described below:

```
class Company(models.Model):
  company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.company_name}"

Class Jobs(models.Model):
  job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  job_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.on_delete=CASCADE)
  job_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  job_salary = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.job_title}"
```

The data present within these tables is as shown below:

```
  COMPANY
--------------------
|   COMPANY_NAME   |
--------------------
|   Google         |
|   Facebook       |
|   Microsoft      |
|   Amazon         |
--------------------

  JOBS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   JOB_TITLE   |  JOB_COMPANY  |   JOB_LOCATION   |  JOB_SALARY  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| ENGINEER      | GOOGLE        | SAN JOSE         |  5000        |
| MANAGER       | AMAZON        | NYC              |  8000        |
| DELIVERY MAN  | AMAZON        | WASHINGTON DC    |  2000        |
| ACCOUNTANT    | MICROSOFT     | SFO              |  4000        |
| SALES LEAD    | GOOGLE        | SFO              |  5000        |
| DESIGNER      | GOOGLE        | NYC              |  3500        |
| CHEF          | GOOGLE        | NYC              |  2500        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to display the following output on my template:

COMPANY NAME ALONG WITH THE NUMBER OF JOBS BEING OFFERED AT THE COMPANY IN DESCENDING ORDER AS SHOWN BELOW.

```
GOOGLE (4)
AMAZON (2)
MICROSOFT (1)
```

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's `Count` [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) on a queryset to accomplish this. In your `Views.py` do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(count = Count('Google'))
dict1= {}
for each in queryset:
   #print(each.my_charfield, each.count)
   context[each.my_charfield] = each.count 

return render(request, 'some.html', context=dict1)
```

In the template access it like

```
{% for key, value in dict1.items %}
     {{key}} ({{value}}) 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the views.py file:

```
def company(request):
    comp_details = Company.objects.annotate(jobs=Count('job')).order_by('-jobs')[:10]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'comp_details': comp_details})
```

Within the index.html file:

```
{% for company in comp_details %}
   {{ company.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This would display the Top 10 companies, based on the number of jobs being offered by them.